# Using DAAB to update a DataTable without a DataSet

Tags: daab

Currently, there is only UpdateDataSet function that takes a dataset param.  If there is only a datatable to update, with no dataset associated, do I need to create a dataset just to pass it in?  Any way to update just a table?

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to create a dummy dataset and add your table to that dataset.  Then, call UpdateDataSet...